# Open A File Via Html Button

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am looking for a way to open a file when user clicks on the *open button* on my website.

Basically, I want to *define the path to that specific file* that I want the html button to open.

Comment: open a file WHERE? on their device? some other site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read about it in another post. Try using this:

`<a href="path_to_file" download="proposed_file_name">Download</a>`

Where :

path_to_file is either an absolute or relative path,
proposed_file_name the filename to save to (can be blank, then defaults to the actual filename).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/filepath/file.pdf" target="_blank"><input type="button" value="Open File" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

you can open up a file dialog.  You'll have to handle this with PHP.
This link: https://www.sitepoint.com/handle-file-uploads-php/ provides all the info you need.  If you don't have a server to upload .php files to, you can set up a LAMP server.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I think the question is related to displaying file on button click and not file upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the button:

```
onclick="window.open('file_url')"
```