# React js: How to open a local path via HTML button on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How do I open a local path on my computer, say `/home/mypath/Desktop/Projects/projectFolder1/` using an `HTML` button on my webpage? 
I am trying to do this because I would like to dump a certain amount of `.pdf` documents inside the folder.

Below the code that I am using:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle } from 'reactstrap';
import '../components/SideBar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import example from '../documents/sample.zip';
import example2 from '../documents/example1.pdf';


class AtchafalayaButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <DownloadLink src={example}>Download Project Specs</DownloadLink>;
    }
}
class DownloadLink extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form method="get" action={this.props.src}>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">
                    {this.props.children}
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}


const Sidebar = () => (
    <div className="map-sidebar">
        <Card className="mb-2">
            <CardImg />
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                </CardTitle>
                <CardSubtitle>Title Section</CardSubtitle>
                <CardText>
                    <h6>Project Details</h6>
                </CardText>
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <AtchafalayaButton />
                </div>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
```

1) I tried the following approach but realized that it was not correct as I am not trying to `download`

```
            <a href="path_to_file" download="proposed_file_name">
```

but I am trying to open `/home/mypath/Desktop/Projects/projectFolder1/` using an `HTML` button on my webpage.

2) Therefore I dug more into the problem and found [this source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-file-paths/) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045479/open-a-file-via-html-button). However they don't seem to address properly the problem.

3) I stepped back and tried to look at something less advanced but with more explanation on how to do that and found [this basic example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) which sort of helps me but than it nevers explains how to open up or set a local folder.

4) After digging more I came across [this other source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870711/download-a-file-at-different-location-using-html5) which makes me a bit concerned as in the same source there is a [link to this other source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840923/get-browser-download-path-with-javascript/9840961#9840961) which explain that apparently it is not possible. However that link is almost 5 years old and maybe something else that I am not aware of already exists.

Please point to the right direction as I am running out of ideas and options on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side JS does not have access to files and folders on User's PC. I doubt that will be changed anytime in future. The only thing you can do with JS is initiate save dialog using package like [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver).

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. I am reading this source but have a quick question. If I would like to dump say 10 `pdf` in my local path `/home/mypath/Desktop/Projects/projectFolder1/` via button on my webpage I can still do it? From the `file-saver` it seems possible but the operation seems to happen asynchronously?

Comment: You can offer user to download file but you can't select folder or control download process. For example, when you call `FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");`, browser would just open File save dialog and it's up to user to decide where to store it

Comment: Perfect, and one last question. Can the user decide to upload files?

Comment: For example the user click the button and decides to upload a file in the same folder `/home/mypath/Desktop/Projects/projectFolder1/`?

Comment: What do you mean, upload? Uploading files to server is totally different operation