# How to upload a document to a local path via HTML web page button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a small webpage as example that looks like the one below. I have a certain number of users who can use that application and I would like to have the possibility for the user to upload one or more files to `ShareSync` on a specific folder.

The order of operation is therefore the following:

Take `.pdf` from Desktop-> open path using webpage button as shown -> access to `ShareSync` specific folder -> upload `.pdf` in that folder

[image: save]

Would that be possible?

Below the code I am using for far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle } from 'reactstrap';
import '../components/SideBar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import example from '../documents/sample.zip';
import example2 from '../documents/example1.pdf';


class AtchafalayaButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <DownloadLink src={example}>Download Project Specs</DownloadLink>;
    }
}
class DownloadLink extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form method="get" action={this.props.src}>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">
                    {this.props.children}
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}


const Sidebar = () => (
    <div className="map-sidebar">
        <Card className="mb-2">
            <CardImg />
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                </CardTitle>
                <CardSubtitle>Title Section</CardSubtitle>
                <CardText>
                    <h6>Project Details</h6>
                </CardText>
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <AtchafalayaButton />
                </div>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I consulted [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) but this does not seem to be what I want because the user has to `upload` a file into a folder and not `download` from the folder.

2) I dug into the problem and found [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-file-paths/) source and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045479/open-a-file-via-html-button) one too. However they don't seem to address properly the problem I have.

3) I stepped back and tried to look at something less advanced but with more explanation on how to do that and found [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) basic example which sort of helps me but it is mostly aimed at `downloading` and not at `uploading` a file to a specific location.

4) After digging more I came across [this other source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840923/get-browser-download-path-with-javascript/9840961#9840961) from which it is not clear if this operation is possible.

Please point to the right direction as I am running out of ideas and options on how to solve this problem.

Comment: What is ShareSync? Maybe it has an API you can use to upload files. Does it have any documentation you could look at (and give us a link to)? From a browser you can only upload files to a remote server via HTTP. You cannot "upload" then to a "local path" (by which I assume you mean a file on the same device as the browser is running on), because a) the browser doesn't have permissions to write to local paths, and b) that's a pretty nonsensical requirement anyway, because the user could just copy the file to that folder in the normal way, without involving a web page.

Comment: ShareSync is a [sharing service](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/sharesync/9wzdncrdlbqs?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) where you can create/erase folders. Only subscibed users can access to it.

Comment: Ok. So that links us to the app in a store. Where's the product website? Do they have an API? Do they have documentation? You didn't answer that bit.

Comment: Sorry, so [here](https://sharesync.serverdata.net/Downloads/ShareSync/documents/ShareSync%20Get%20Started%20Guide%20for%20Windows.pdf) is the link to the product. As far as I can [see](https://kb.smarshmail.com/Article/3361?query=tag%3d%22ShareSync%22) from the website there is no API available.

Comment: Maybe is there another product I can use instead?

Comment: It sounds very similar to lots of products - OneDrive, Google Drive, Dropbox, etc etc etc. And all of those have APIs.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about Google Drive API! Nice to know and I will use that as it seems more easy and documentation is available! Thanks!